# BlackBerry 8330 connection issue

Tags: blackberry, java-me, jsr172

I'm able to connect to a webservice and download the data using a variety of devices, such as the BlackBerry 9000 with OS 4.6 or greater.

However, with the 8330 and OS 4.5.0.77 it doesn't work.  I have not tried this code on any devices older than the 8330 with 4.5.0.77.
On the 8330 it hangs on the `resultObj = op.invoke(inputObject);` line in the JSR172 webservice call.  This is after making the first webservice call successfully -- it hangs on the second.

There are actually two webservices:

1. The webservice used for authentication.
2. The webservice used to download all the information.

Things I've tried thus far:

1. Wiping the device - did nothing
2. Connecting the device to Eclipse to see what is going on - didn't find anything useful
3. Running the code on a 8330 simulator with 4.5 (MDS running)- works flawlessly with no problems

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Here is how I build my connection string:

```
    String webserviceURL = developmentUrl;

    // if it is simulator then force the network that is available on
    // the PC
    if (DeviceInfo.isSimulator()) {
        webserviceURL += ";deviceside=true";
    } else if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) {
        // go through MDS
        webserviceURL += ";deviceside=false";
    }
    // else if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() &
    // CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_CARRIER) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_CARRIER)
    // {
    // webserviceURL += "'deviceside=true";// go direct
    // }

    // check if the wifi is available and change the url to use the wifi
    // signal
    if ((RadioInfo.getActiveWAFs() & RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN) != 0)
    // check for carrier
    {
        if (WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED)
        // check for wifi
        {
            // WebService URL when the app is being used in the
            // actual device
            webserviceURL = webserviceURL + ";interface=wifi";
        }
    }

    // WebService URL when the app is being used in the actual device
    _propertyValues = new Object[] { webserviceURL };
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by going to ~50k chunks for the data.  I'm happy to help anyone who has a similar issue.